# The Campaign status cannot be changed to Complete until Results & Recommendations field has been populated

Tags: validation-rule, validation

I have this validation rule, but not sure what I am doing wrong. This validation rule doesn't prevent the Campaign Status being changed to 'Complete' even though the Results & Recommendation field has not been populated. I need to not be able to change the Status to Complete if this field is blank.

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(Status),
ISPICKVAL( Status ,"Completed"),
OR(RecordType.Name ="Campaign Standard"),
OR (ISBLANK( Name ),
ISBLANK( Results_Recommendations__c ))))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. We don't know what your records look like and therefore can't say why this formula doesn't work.

Comment: N.B. Use `RecordType.DeveloperName` for more robustness

Answer (score 0):

Re-formatting this as:

```
AND(
   ISCHANGED(Status),
   ISPICKVAL( Status ,"Completed"),
   OR(
      RecordType.Name ="Campaign Standard"),
      OR(
         ISBLANK( Name ),
         ISBLANK( Results_Recommendations__c )
      )
   )
)
```

Seems to exempt the "Campaign Standard" RecordType from this rule.  Was that your intention?

---

- Consider ISNEW() in here somewhere.  ISCHANGED() does not trigger for new records since there is no PRIORVALUE() to compare to.  That has bitten me a couple of times.
- Consider using RecordType.DeveloperName instead.  It will save you later when you change the label.